# Disable button when validation fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, laravel-4.2

I have one form which has one submit button ,
I want to disable submit button until all validations are true.

currently when one validation gets true , button gets enable. (even other fields has red error message.)

```
<script>           
     $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                    $('#payment-form').formValidation({
                      framework: 'bootstrap',
                      trigger: 'change',
                      fields: {
                        first_name: {
                          validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                              message: 'The First Name field is required and cannot be empty'
                            }
                            // regexp: {
                            // regexp: /^[a-z\\s]+$/i,
                            // message: 'The first name field can consist of alphabetical characters and spaces only'
                            // }
                          }
                        },
                        last_name: {
                          validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                              message: 'The Last Name is required and cannot be empty'
                            }
                            // regexp: {
                            // regexp: /^[a-z\\s]+$/i,
                            // message: 'The Last name can consist of alphabetical characters and spaces only'
                            // }
                          }
                        },
    }
                      });


                 }).on('success.form.fv', function (e) {
                  $('#continue_btn').attr('disabled','false');
                   e.preventDefault();

                    });
                    var i = 0;
                    var l=0;

                    $('#zip_code').keydown(function()
                    {

                      var country_check = $('#country').val();
                      if(country_check=='India')
                      {
                        $('#zip_code').attr('maxlength', '6');
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        $('#zip_code').attr('maxlength', '10');
                      }

                    });
</script>
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

set below properties in formValidation, as here you can see in the form settings: http://formvalidation.io/settings/

```
$('#data_form').formValidation({
...
   button: {
       selector: "#id_submit_btn",
       disabled: "disabled"
   }
....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggle` on the submit button.

```
$('button[data-toggle]').on('click', function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('data-toggle'));
    $target.toggle();
    if (!$target.is(':visible')) {                         
        $('#payment-form').data('formValidation').disableSubmitButtons(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: i think question is around how to trap the event of  if all the fields are valid or if any field is invalid

Comment: @JigarJoshi Yes, but how to validate the input just right after document load? Or before the submit event was trigger. This will disabling the button after first try of submit and will keep disabled til all input is valid.